# How can I get the app icon with the app title on the action bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

In Android , I am trying to set the app icon to the left of its title in the actionBar.

In the MainActivity, I am extending from `Activity`. Here is my code:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_monica_logo)
```

I also changed my Manifest to :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_monica_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I even extended MainActivity to use AppCompatActivity (which I don't want to use):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher_monica_logo);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

... and change the theme in the manifest too

But here I am not getting anything except the title.

How can I get the app icon with the app title on the action bar and then aligned them to the left ?

**UOPDATE:**

Here is me MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#232222">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startServiceBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/killServiceBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@layout/service_action_btns_layout"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/startBgServiceBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/killServiceBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startServiceBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:background="@layout/service_action_btns_layout"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/killBgServiceBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/simulateGeofeneEntryBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:background="@layout/simulate_geofence_btn_layout"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/simulateGeofeneEntryBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what does your main activity xml look like? I have to assume you have a toolbar in there? pretty straight forward from there...

Comment: @DroiDev : Please check the update for the `MainActivity.xml` .. what am I missing

Comment: youre missing a toolbar.... google ToolBar android.

Comment: @DroiDev : On another app, I do not have Google ToolBar Android but it is visible !!  ... beisde , I want the default android ActionBar

Comment: whats your theme?

Comment: @DroiDev : I am not defining any Theme in my Manifest because when I define a Theme the whole actionBar disappears (remove it and it will show according to an answer here on StackOverflow)  ..  Now I have the actionBar with the title but without the app's icon which I want to display too

Comment: lookie here. https://gist.github.com/cyrilmottier/7085463